# Setup ChicagoBoss with all deps to ERL_LIBS

Tags: erlang, environment-variables, chicagoboss

I try to set up ChicagoBoss with all it's dependencies to `ERL_LIBS` environment variable. I got ChicagoBoss, compiled it with `./rebar get-deps && ./rebar compile`, now i have ChicagoBoss in `/home/user/ChicagoBoss` directory and it's dependencies in `/home/user/ChicagoBoss/deps` directory. I want to add it to `ERL_LIBS`. I put to my `.bashrc` file following line:

`export ERL_LIBS=/home/user/ChicagoBoss/:/home/user/*/deps/*/`

But when i try something from ChicagoBoss dependencies, `ranch` application for example with:

`application:start(ranch).`

I got error:

```
{error,{"no such file or directory","ranch.app"}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ERL_LIBS` environment variable has no notion of wildcards. When you start the `erl` with an argument like `-pa deps/*/ebin`, your *shell* is expanding the wildcard. You need to manually add every library path (the path to the *application*, not its `ebin` directory!) to `ERL_LIBS`.

To simplify this process we can use Python:

```
import glob
print ':'.join(glob.glob('/home/user/*/deps/*/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an identical error with a simple application. It turned out that there was a missing 'dep' directory in the main application directory: ranch was installed there. I don't know why it was missing in my case, but I solved it by copying that directory from another working ranch application.

EDIT:
Interestingly, I had got a message compiling saying:
"Dependency not available: ranch-.* ({git,"git://github.com/extend/ranch.git",
                                    "master"})"
which must have been a warning about the missing 'dep' top-level directory.

Answer (score 0):

**ERL_LIBS** can simply point to the parent directory where all your dependencies projects reside. If your projects follow the Erlang Project directory convention ( yourproject/src, yourproject/ebin, yourproject/include ) then Erlang will dynamically associate the ebin and include from those projects to your context.

Example

```
/place/Project1

/place/Project1/ebin/...
/place/Project1/include/...
/place/Project1/deps/...
/place/Project1/deps/DependencyProject2...
/place/Project1/deps/DependencyProject3...
```

As it canbe seen above, **/place/Project1/deps** is the container for other sub-projects ( dependencies ). In this case if you can run your application as

erl env ERL_LIBS "/place:/place/Project1/deps". This will include all related projects ( Project1, DependencyProject2 and DependencyProject3 ) in your runtime context.